# How to do a redirect to different domain but same directory for all links site wide? Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

We have an old domain on an old shopify site. We have a new domain on a new wordpress website.

Our goal is to re-direct all old links from the old site/domain to the new site domain.

For example if a user goes to www.old-website.com/collection/product

it will re-direct them to www.new-website.com/collection/product.

So basically i wana keep /collection/product but swap out the rest of the domain.

I am using this script but i think its too simple and just re-directing to the home page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "https://new-website.com"
</script>
```

So instead of simply changing the location to the new domain. How do I keep the directories but change the domain and then re-direct?

Comment: Consider using **.htaccess Redirect Rule 301**. It's a more recommended method for redirecting links. You can have a wildcard for the entire domain. (It's also better for SEO reasons).

Comment: Can you do that on shopify?

Comment: Check with host and set up a permanent redirect so SEO re-indexes properly. Javascript concept is a very poor approach

Answer (score 1):

If you are forced to do it with JavaScript, then simply try

```js
location.hostname = 'new-website.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the entire url (`document.location.href`) and split the parameters to append it to the new url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var restOfTheUrl = domainName.split('old-website.com')[1] || ''; 
        window.location.href = "https://new-website.com" + restOfTheUrl;
</script>
```

If your user will go to `www.old-website.com/collection/product`

The entire path (except old domain) is appended to the new domain and the result url it will look like this `https://new-website.com/collection/product`

Comment: what if hash or query params exist?

Comment: @charlietfl You are totally right, I forgot to take in consideration this.  I modified my response according.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking a little out of the box. If you have access to the DNS, you can easily do that using use the [redirect.center](http://redirect.center/) service.

You need to add / modify 2 records of the `old-website.com` zone:

- Add an A record to redirect http://old-website.com to http://www.old-website.com.
- Than add a CNAME record  to redirect http://www.old-website.com to http://new-website.com

---

```
@   A     54.84.55.102
www CNAME new-website.com
```

---

The advantage is that this is a **301 redirect** which is better for SEO. Also you can remove your old website, possibly saving some bucks.

Comment: @adricadar No, the service can only redirect naked domain to `www` of the same domain. So first you redirect to `www.old-website.com` and than to `new-website.com`.